# The text file specification does not exist

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-csv, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to run a simple access program that exports data from a select query. However I keep getting the error:

> Run-time error '3625'
>   The text file specification 'Deposits Link Specification' does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification.

I didn't set up a text file specification, mainly because I haven't had to do this before. How would I go about fixing this?

My simple code, is below:

```
'*************************************************************************
Public Function startupdate()
'*************************************************************************
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "DepositsToChecklist", "X:\InHouseApps\SummerCamps\TMS\EEChecklistImport.csv", True
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryAppendDepositsToChecklist"
    DoCmd.Quit

End Function
```

Comment: I found this, "For delimited text files and Microsoft Word mail merge data files, you can leave this argument blank to select the default import/export specifications." which is what I'm doing.

Comment: I see you are "leaving the argument blank."  To which argument are you referring?  And, should I take your comment to indicate the problem you had is now solved?